# python pandas find closes value from other list and add to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have a new column ( x_last_turn_temp) with the closest values from X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER to the currente x_temp.

```
X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER = [3,10,17,24,31,38,45,52,59,66,73,80,87,94,101,108,115,122,129,136]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_temp': [7,8,21,22,35,36,49,50,63,64,77,78,91,92,105,106,119,120,133,134]})
```

at the end the `df['x_last_turn_temp']` should look like this

```
df['x_last_turn_temp'] = [10,10,24,24,38,38,52,52,66,66,80,80,94,94,108,108,122,122,136,136]
```

I have tried this, but it does not work

```
df['x_last_turn_temp'] = min(enumerate(X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER), key=lambda x: abs(x - df['x_temp']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `pd.merge_asof`

[From the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

> This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key
> rather than equal keys. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

#### Note:

I use the `direction` argument to specify that I want to use the values `'nearest'`.

```
XTSN = pd.DataFrame({'X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER': X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER})

pd.merge_asof(
    df, XTSN,
    left_on='x_temp',
    right_on='X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER',
    direction='nearest',
)

    x_temp  X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER
0        7                    10
1        8                    10
2       21                    24
3       22                    24
4       35                    38
5       36                    38
6       49                    52
7       50                    52
8       63                    66
9       64                    66
10      77                    80
11      78                    80
12      91                    94
13      92                    94
14     105                   108
15     106                   108
16     119                   122
17     120                   122
18     133                   136
19     134                   136
```

---

#### Setup

```
X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER = [
    3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38, 45, 52, 59, 66, 73,
    80, 87, 94, 101, 108, 115, 122, 129, 136
]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x_temp': [
        7, 8, 21, 22, 35, 36, 49, 50, 63, 64, 77,
        78, 91, 92, 105, 106, 119, 120, 133, 134
    ]
})
```

Comment: It needs to work where the length of the arrays are not the same. One array could change to: X_TURN_STREET_NUMBER = [31,38,45,52,59,66,73,80,87,94,101,108]

Comment: It works with that as well, use `'nearest'` instead of `'forward'`.  Also, it has nothing to do with length.  It has to do with the greatest value being less than the greatest value in the left dataframe coupled with my choice of using `'forward'`

Comment: Thank you. Works very well.